# Getting an error while updating core to version 8.7.0

Tags: entities

When update Drupal 8.6 to 8.7 getting the following error. Anyone help would be appreciated.

```
TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Drupal\views\EntityViewsData::mapFieldDefinition() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface, null given, called in /Users/punya/htdocs/un-nip/core/modules/views/src/EntityViewsData.php on line 290 in Drupal\views\EntityViewsData->mapFieldDefinition() (line 387 of core/modules/views/src/EntityViewsData.php).


Drupal\views\EntityViewsData->mapFieldDefinition('file_managed', 'type', NULL, Object, Array) (Line: 290)
Drupal\views\EntityViewsData->getViewsData() (Line: 16)
Drupal\file\FileViewsData->getViewsData() (Line: 178)
views_views_data()
call_user_func_array('views_views_data', Array) (Line: 392)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('views', 'views_data') (Line: 243)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 160)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('node_field_data') (Line: 85)
Drupal\views\Plugin\ViewsHandlerManager->getHandler(Array, NULL) (Line: 889)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getHandlers('sort') (Line: 1040)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->_initHandler('sort', Array) (Line: 898)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->initHandlers() (Line: 2267)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->preExecute() (Line: 1692)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->preExecute(Array) (Line: 1627)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('page_1', Array) (Line: 77)
Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 693)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just worked through a similar issue.  Yours may not be exactly the same, but I had to do two things. (1) Remove all old code associated with 8.6 and older versions.  Basically, instead of copying 8.7 on top of 8.6, I deleted everything except my sites directory from 8.6, and copied the 8.7 files and folders fresh.  (2) In sites/all/modules, I was using profile.  Apparently, this module is not compatible with 8.7, at least the version I am using.  Removing this folder completely allowed my site to upgrade with no further issues.  There may be other contributed modules that also have issues with 8.7.